# format string exploitation, how can I retrieve saved istruction pointer?

Tags: c, exploit, format-string

I have a problem with my exploit (doing for exercise).
The string to pass to my vulnerable program is ready except for the target address where I want to write, of course it is the current saved $eip.

How can I retrieve it? The answer seems to be easy, by debugging of course, stop the execution and see the address printing the stack. Ok let's assume now that I retrieved it, the problem is that I launch an executable not compiled with the -g option, so no way to set breakpoints... so How can I do that?

Note that, the two stack (one of the file compiled with -g and the one without it) are different!! different stack, so different $eip address (and also value).

Comment: Of course you can set breakpoints even if there's no debugging information, you just can't use line numbers. The symbol table is still present (except if the executable has been stripped), so load it into a disassembler, locate the address of the function you're interested in and look at the assembly to pinpoint the location you're interested in setting a breakpoint for. Then set the breakpoint by programm address.

Comment: Ok now I have the address, when I try to set the breakpoint it says: "make breakpoint pending on future shared library load" so when I run my code the breakpoint seems not existing.

Comment: What command did you use to set this breakpoint? This message normally means, that whatever you told the debugger was interpreted as a compilation unit name and not a program address.

Comment: ok I made it,I found the address in the gdb session, and the exploit is done. but despite all, when I run the executable, the shell doesn't appear!!! I tried to put the same address I found before (and many others) but it seems the address of saved eip was different!

Comment: Haha, yes I was expecting you'd run into a different address. What you just experienced is an exploitation mitigation technology called Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR). In short the operating system loads the sections of the executable at random places of the address space, exactly to mitigate the exploitation technique you're investigating. ASLR has been introduced a few years ago as standard feature in most operating systems.

Comment: To make a long story short: You'll have to look into exploitation techniques that are independent of the targeted exectuables address space layout.

Comment: for future readings, I finally made it! I just wrote down a script to cycle over all possibile address ( in restricted range to raise down the time effort) and I found it ;) Tunarock 1 ASLR 0

Answer (score 0):

for future readings, I finally made it! I just wrote down a script to cycle over all possibile address ( in restricted range to raise down the time effort) and I found it ;) Tunarock 1 ASLR 0 –  Tunarock